# Retrieve phone number or IMEI of a smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, cross-platform

I'm doing an cross platform app. with MoSynv IDE and I want to retreive a unique ID of one smartphone. Is it  possible to retreive the phone number or the IMEI of the smartphone with JavaScript or with API of MoSync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `device.uuid`
You can use it after including wormhole.js 
[API reference](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/device.uuid.md.html#device.uuid)

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu broo. you help me sooo much :) thank you again

Comment: Where can i download this file?

Comment: 404 page not found :-(