# how to fetch android device IMEI number using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am preparing android hybrid app using html5 and jquery. My project requirement is to fetch device IMEI number using JavaScript/jQuery.
Please help me if any body have any idea about it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you specifically want the IMEI number or any unique device identifier would do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742850/how-to-get-imei-number-in-phonegap

Comment: its answered in the following link too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157220/retrieve-phone-number-or-imei-of-a-smartphone

Comment: @SHANK: yea that would be helpful in itself since a lot of IMEI extraction use-cases just reduce down to having any unique identifier for the user's mobile device (e.g. Sybil detection). What do you propose to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about plain javascript and HTML, I do not think you are able to access the IMEI. This is for security reasons. You would be able to do this with a PhoneGap app or a "normal" native app.

Answer (score -5):

You should add the following permission into your `Manifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And, with the help of following code you can get the IMEI no.:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = 
(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Note: In case of tablets or devices which can’t act as Mobile Phone IMEI will be `null`.

Comment: This is for Android... not Javascript

Comment: The question is related to JavaScript (browser side) not to a native code (app side), so, this is not an acceptable answer